# JS https request returning undefined Response

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, https, request

I am trying to make an API call from my JavaScript app to an endpoint in another application.

When I call the endpoint I get the status code and the message, but I cannot access the response body in any way. I have tried different ways to get the data, but nothing seems to work for me.

In the method "someAction", I want to use the data in the response/result from the API call. I added the outputs that the single log-lines print in the code.

How can "result" be undefined while "result.status/message" are defined?

What do I have to do in order to get the data/body as JSON or String?

The API itself is tested and returns data when tested in postman.

Thanks for your help!

```
const request   = require('request')

let callEndpoint = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const url = `https://my.api.com/endpoint`

        const requestOptions = {
            url: url,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                'My-API-Authorization': '123456789'
            },
            json: true,
            strictSSL: false
        }

        request.get(requestOptions, (err, response) => {
            if(err)
            {
                return reject(err);
            }
            return resolve(response);
        });
    });
}

let someAction = () => {
    callEndpoint()
        .then(result => {
            logger.logInfo(result.statusCode)           // => 200
            logger.logInfo(result.statusMessage)        // => OK
            logger.logInfo(result)                      // => undefined
            logger.logInfo(result.toString())           // => [object Object]
            logger.logInfo(result.body)                 // => undefined
            logger.logInfo(result.data)                 // => undefined

            JSON.parse(result.toString())               // => Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1    
            JSON.parse(result)                          // => Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

            // DO SOME STUFF WITH THE RESULT
        })
}
```

Comment: You are getting a response, you just don't have any data in it. So your call to the API is missing something or your API is failing, but still returning a successful response without the data.

Comment: [The `request` module is deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). Don't use it.

Comment: NodeJS has built in libraries. Here is the doc for HTTPS => https://nodejs.org/api/https.html  and HTTP => https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Comment: @daddygames I tested the API using Postman and I get data there. That's the weird thing.

Comment: It's hard to say what the issue is given the information we have. It's possible that the deprecated library is the problem, but we can't be certain.